# Chave composta com EF FluentAPI

Tags: entity-framework-6, fluent-api

Estou com problemas para definir um relacionamento com chave composta no FluentAPI. Tenho as seguintes entidades: Produto, PessoaFilial e Estoque. Preciso que na tabela estoque eu tenha um FK de produto (ProdutoID) e uma FK de PessoaFilial (FilialID) de forma que não seja possível incluir duas vezes o mesmo produto para uma filial em meu estoque.

Answer (score 0):

Precisa ser por fluent? 
Eu normalmente faço por notação, veja:

```
public class Estoque
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Key,Column(Order = 2)]
    public int FilialID { get; set; }

}
```

Mas por Fluent fica assim:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Estoque>().HasKey(s => new { s.ProductID , s.FilialID });
```